# How to project 2d points to 3d coordinates

Tags: image, 3d, geometry, projection

I have a 3d object and a 2d image. I can pick same points on both 3d object and 2d image. From this how do I calculate the camera translation, position, camera parameters etc and project the 2d image to the 3d object? I can't come up with the math behind this! When I search most of the time I see the opposite, 3d to 2d projection.

Comment: You cannot restore 3d object from its 2d projection.

Comment: But I have the object. I don't need to restore it. Just project the 2d image onto that 3d object. I can pick multiple points on the 3d object and 2d which are same on both. Can't I somehow use that info?

Comment: Every point of 2d corresponds to line (infinity number of points) in 3d. You can find intersection of that line with 3d object.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Can you please suggest any article to read to know more details?